# Why is my CNN not learning

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am sorry for such a cliche question, but I really don't know why my CNN is not improving.

I am training a CNN for SVHN dataset (single digit) with images of 32x32.

For preprocessing, I transform RGB to grayscale and normalize all pixel data by standardization. So the data range becomes (-1,1). To verify that my `X` and `y` correspond to each other correctly, I randomly pick an image from `X` and a label from `y` with the same index, and it shows that they do.

[image]

Here's my code (Keras, tensorflow backend):

```
"""
    Single Digit Recognition
"""

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Convolution2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers.core import Dropout, Flatten
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(16, 5, 5, border_mode='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='default'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='same', input_shape=(16, 16, 16)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='default'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same', input_shape=(32, 8, 8)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, border_mode='same', dim_ordering='default'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=1024))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=128))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_X, train_y,
          validation_split=0.1,
          nb_epoch=20,
          batch_size=64)
score = model.evaluate(test_X, test_y, batch_size=16)
```

After running 10 epochs, the accuracy is still the same as in the first epoch, and that's why I stopped it.

```
Train on 65931 samples, validate on 7326 samples
Epoch 1/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 190s - loss: 2.2390 - acc: 0.1882 - val_loss: 2.2447 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 2/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 194s - loss: 2.2395 - acc: 0.1893 - val_loss: 2.2399 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 3/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 167s - loss: 2.2393 - acc: 0.1893 - val_loss: 2.2402 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 4/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 172s - loss: 2.2394 - acc: 0.1883 - val_loss: 2.2443 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 5/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 172s - loss: 2.2393 - acc: 0.1884 - val_loss: 2.2443 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 6/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 179s - loss: 2.2397 - acc: 0.1881 - val_loss: 2.2433 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 7/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 173s - loss: 2.2399 - acc: 0.1888 - val_loss: 2.2410 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 8/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 175s - loss: 2.2392 - acc: 0.1893 - val_loss: 2.2439 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 9/20
65931/65931 [==============================] - 175s - loss: 2.2395 - acc: 0.1893 - val_loss: 2.2401 - val_acc: 0.1885
Epoch 10/20
 9536/65931 [===>..........................] - ETA: 162s - loss: 2.2372 - acc: 0.1909
```

Should I keep trying with more patience or is there something wrong with my CNN?

Comment: Try lowering your learning rate. 0.1 is huge. Try something like 1e-5

Comment: Agree that the learning rate is too large. In addition, try normalizing your data into the range of [0,1] instead of [-1,1].

Comment: @pyan why do you suggest to scale the input values between [0,1] instead of [-1,1]?

Comment: Since you use ReLU as activation function, it gives you 0 if the input is less than 0. So [0,1] range may train faster than [-1,1], given the same initial parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your optimizer to Adam, as it is more capable than SGD. You can include Nesterov momentum with nAdam. So i would try the following.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='nadam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This will adjust learning rates automatically and you don't need to worry about it as much.